# Laravel & Eloquent: Correct way to save data simultaneously to two models which requires the id of each of them as the foreign key in the other

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

When a new page is created part of that data goes to the slugs model (slug url, template type, template id) this is standard on every page, then the rest of the data goes to a template model, in this case called text (simple text page).

The slug is required for example.com/{slug} which grabs the slug_url and looks for the appropriate page/template to produce the correct view and pass the correct data.

Logic:

```
Slug requires Text id
Text requires Slug id
```

But as I have to save them at the same time I’m not sure how I get the id of one and pass it to the other, simultaneously, so I came up with this:

1. Save new Slug
2. Save new Text (page template)
3. Update Slug with Text id

Here is the offending code - TextsController:

```
public function store()
{

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'title'      => 'required',
            'slug_url'   => 'required',
            'menu_order' => 'required|numeric'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()) { 

        Flash::error('Page not created! Please check errors below');
        return Redirect::route('app.pages.index')->withErrors($validator);

    } else {

        $slug = new Slug;
        $slug->user_id     = Auth::id();
        $slug->slug_url    = Input::get('slug_url');
        $slug->type        = Input::get('type');
        $slug->menu_order  = Input::get('menu_order');
        $slug->save();

        $text = new Text;
        $text->user_id = Auth::id();
        $text->slug_id = $slug->id;
        $text->title   = Input::get('title');
        $text->active  = Input::get('active');
        $text->save();

        $slug_update = Slug::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('slug_url', $slug->slug_url)->first();
        $slug_update->type_id = $text->id;
        $slug_update->update();

        return Redirect::route('app.texts.edit', $text->id);

    }

}
```

I’m pretty new to Laravel (and development generally) but from what I have see so far, I’m pretty sure there must a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change those lines:

```
   $slug_update = Slug::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('slug_url', $slug->slug_url)->first();
   $slug_update->type_id = $text->id;
   $slug_update->update();
```

into:

```
   $slug->type_id = $text->id;
   $slug->save();
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin that has worked. So just to confirm the three step process of Save Slug, Save Text then update Slug is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @JackBarham Yes, I think in this case there is no other way. However it's very strange you have foreign keys in both tables, normally you use it just in once table, not in 2

Comment: I'm just experimenting at the moment, getting used to saving and creating pages. As it stands now (and will likely change) I need to call a page_template from a slug_url->id for the user public front-end pages and in the admin area I need the slug from the associated page_template->id - Once I get better that I'm sure it will change :)